# TweenMax after animation finished

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

When first animation will be done after that I want another animation on the same target.

```
var lnk = document.querySelector('#clickme');
var tl = new TimelineMax();

lnk.addEventListener('click', go, false);

function go(){
    tl.to('.glasko', 1, {width: 500, height: 500});
};
```

After that I want to change background color of div.

```
tl.to('.glasko', 2, {backgroundColor: 'red'});
```

What is best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GSAP` makes it easy & simple with `TimelineMax`. You just need to write second animation after first animation using same `TimelineMax` instance and this is the best approach.

```
var lnk = document.querySelector('#clickme');
var tl = new TimelineMax();

lnk.addEventListener('click', go, false);

function go(){
    tl.to('.glasko', 1, {width: 500, height: 500});
    tl.to('.glasko', 2, {backgroundColor: 'red'});
};
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vgyntz0g/)